# How to add up minutes and seconds in continuation from previous input

Tags: java, java-time, duration

I am trying to figure out how to add up the minutes and seconds a user inputs. I'm not adding from a current time so I know I need a loop that will add up all the minutes entered and seconds. I also want the seconds that add to 60 to be added to the minutes instead of it listing as a bunch of seconds. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class timeAdder {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner keyb = new Scanner (System.in);
         System.out.println ("Welcome to the Time Adder!\n ");
         System.out.println("Enter 5 time durations in minutes and seconds\n ");
         
         System.out.print ("Duration 1, how many minutes? ");
         int min = keyb.nextInt();
         System.out.print ("Duration 1, how many seconds? ");
         int sec = keyb.nextInt();
         System.out.print ("Duration 2, how many minutes? ");
         min=keyb.nextInt();
         System.out.print ("Duration 2, how many seconds? ");
         sec= keyb.nextInt();
         System.out.print ("Duration 3, how many minutes? ");
         min = keyb.nextInt();
         System.out.print ("Duration 3, how many seconds? ");
         sec = keyb.nextInt();
         System.out.print ("Duration 4, how many minutes? ");
         min = keyb.nextInt();
         System.out.print ("Duration 4, how many seconds? ");
         sec = keyb.nextInt();
         System.out.print ("Duration 5, how many minutes? ");
         min = keyb.nextInt();
         System.out.print ("Duration 5, how many seconds? ");
         sec = keyb.nextInt();

         System.out.println("The total of the 5 times is: \n");         
     }
}
```

Comment: Note: you have a lot of repeated code. You could use a (`for`) loop instead.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) which is modelled on [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and was introduced with *Java-8* as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html). With *Java-9* some more convenience methods were introduced.

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);
        Duration duration = Duration.ZERO;

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Time Adder!\n ");
        System.out.println("Enter 5 time durations in minutes and seconds\n ");

        System.out.print("Duration 1, how many minutes? ");
        duration = duration.plusMinutes(keyb.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Duration 1, how many seconds? ");
        duration = duration.plusSeconds(keyb.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Duration 2, how many minutes? ");
        duration = duration.plusMinutes(keyb.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Duration 2, how many seconds? ");
        duration = duration.plusSeconds(keyb.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Duration 3, how many minutes? ");
        duration = duration.plusMinutes(keyb.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Duration 3, how many seconds? ");
        duration = duration.plusSeconds(keyb.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Duration 4, how many minutes? ");
        duration = duration.plusMinutes(keyb.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Duration 4, how many seconds? ");
        duration = duration.plusSeconds(keyb.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Duration 5, how many minutes? ");
        duration = duration.plusMinutes(keyb.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Duration 5, how many seconds? ");
        duration = duration.plusSeconds(keyb.nextInt());

        // In default format
        System.out.println(duration);

        // Custom format
        // ####################################Java-8####################################
        String formattedElapsedTime = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", duration.toHours() % 24,
                duration.toMinutes() % 60, duration.toSeconds() % 60);
        System.out.println("The total of the 5 times is: " + formattedElapsedTime);
        // ##############################################################################

        // ####################################Java-9####################################
        formattedElapsedTime = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", duration.toHoursPart(), duration.toMinutesPart(),
                duration.toSecondsPart());
        System.out.println("The total of the 5 times is: " + formattedElapsedTime);
        // ##############################################################################

    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Welcome to the Time Adder!
 
Enter 5 time durations in minutes and seconds
 
Duration 1, how many minutes? 5
Duration 1, how many seconds? 10
Duration 2, how many minutes? 15
Duration 2, how many seconds? 20
Duration 3, how many minutes? 25
Duration 3, how many seconds? 30
Duration 4, how many minutes? 35
Duration 4, how many seconds? 40
Duration 5, how many minutes? 45
Duration 5, how many seconds? 50
PT2H7M30S
The total of the 5 times is: 02:07:30
The total of the 5 times is: 02:07:30
```

### Further improvement:

I recommend you use a loop for the five groups of inputs.

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);
        Duration duration = Duration.ZERO;

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Time Adder!\n ");
        System.out.println("Enter 5 time durations in minutes and seconds\n ");

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            System.out.print("Duration " + i + ", how many minutes? ");
            duration = duration.plusMinutes(keyb.nextInt());
            System.out.print("Duration " + i + ", how many seconds? ");
            duration = duration.plusSeconds(keyb.nextInt());
        }

        // In default format
        System.out.println(duration);

        // Custom format
        // ####################################Java-8####################################
        String formattedElapsedTime = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", duration.toHours() % 24,
                duration.toMinutes() % 60, duration.toSeconds() % 60);
        System.out.println("The total of the 5 times is: " + formattedElapsedTime);
        // ##############################################################################

        // ####################################Java-9####################################
        formattedElapsedTime = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", duration.toHoursPart(), duration.toMinutesPart(),
                duration.toSecondsPart());
        System.out.println("The total of the 5 times is: " + formattedElapsedTime);
        // ##############################################################################

    }
}
```

Comment: how do i display the total of the times in words like i.e "27 minutes and 5 seconds"

Comment: Thanks, Ole. @user15200162 - If you haven't been able to figure out yet what Ole has suggested or if you are struggling to use `printf`, you can use `System.out.println("The total of the 5 times is " + duration.toHoursPart() + " hours "
    + duration.toMinutesPart() + " minutes and " + duration.toSecondsPart() + " seconds.")`. However, I strongly recommend you go through https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html and practice  the examples there.

Comment: it quite literally has to be in minutes and seconds. like it cant display 0 hours anymore and im having a hard time fixing that

Comment: @user15200162 - In that case, it should be `System.out.println("The total of the 5 times is " + duration.toMinutes() + " minutes and "
    + duration.toSecondsPart() + " seconds.")`

Answer (score 0):

Add up all the minutes and seconds separately, then do

```
min+=sec/60; 
sec=sec%60;
```

i.e.

```
     ...
     System.out.print ("Duration 2, how many minutes? ");
     min+=keyb.nextInt();
     System.out.print ("Duration 2, how many seconds? ");
     sec+= keyb.nextInt();
     ...
     min+=sec/60; 
     sec=sec%60;
```